# Android Studio OpenCV NDK: Unspecified error, The function is not implemented

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, gtk, highgui

I write in Android Studio on Windows. And I use OpenCV in my native c++ code.When calling the function, I get this error in logcat:

> "OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented.
>   Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
>   are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
>   re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file
>   /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp,
>   line 545".

I found different instructions how to do it in LInux but not any for Windows. Who knows how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error means, that I cannot use opencv's gui / windowing functions on android, since window functions work much different there, than on a desktop pc.

This means, that I cannot use imshow() namedWindow() createTrackBar() or waitKey() , but have to use the native android equivalent

(it's neither a windows, not a linux problem, and recompiling won't change it)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is that your library (build from NDK-Build) built wrongly or doesn't exist. Therefore, whichever OpenCV  C++ Library you are accessing does not exist.

You will need to JAVAH your java files (whichever that will be having Native C++) code and then NDK-Build the generated CPP files.

Of course, you will require a custom Android.MK and Application.MK which OpenCV documents it at their official website at [here!](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#native-c)

Comment: I write in Android Studio 1.5.1. There are no longer used mk files for the NDK.

Comment: @imported_lis they do, you require the use of depreciated NDK at gradle.properties. I've done mine just 4 days ago! =)